# Increase size of flag "other" reason box

Tags: feature-request, flags, design

Typing a decent explanation can quickly fill up the reason box in flag post -> it needs ♦ moderator attention -> other (just from a display perspective, not the amount of text allowed).

Can this box be enlarged, or can we be given a "corner-thingy" to enlarge it ourselves (like the add-comment box)?

[image]

Example of add-comment "corner-thingy":

[image]

Comment: +1 for corner-thingys. Even though I thought that was provided by the browser, not the website.

Comment: Just curious, how often are you writing such detailed flag descriptions that you exceed the box without also coming dangerously close to exceeding the character limit and likely having to revise anyway?

Comment: @CodyGray The feature itself is implemented by the browser, but you can control it with the CSS `resize` property.

Comment: @animuson yep, there a CSS rule in place `resize: none;` though I wonder why...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Not particularly often. I don't usually write such long reasons, but note that you still have another 253 characters left when the box wraps. Simply posting 2 question links basically gets you there.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd maybe to prevent people from unknowingly pushing the "characters left" counter off the dialog? Haven't inspected the CSS so I don't know if the outer container is set to overflow, scroll, or what.

Comment: @AaronBertrand just tried, resizing the textarea cause the whole dialog to stretch downwards, "characters left" stick below the textarea though: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ool87.png