# Increase message size for “other” flag details

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags, character-limit

When user wants to flag some comment and select “something else”  there is a prompt “problem not listed above. Try to be as specific as possible.”.

Unfortunately the message size is only 200 characters, and it is not enough to provide all details.

Could you please Increase message size for flag detail.

I’ve noticed that 7 years ago total limit was more than 300 [Increase size of flag "other" reason box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193076/163139)

Comment: the 200 chars limit  is for comment flags, not for posts flags where it is 500 (?). If I can't fit it in 200 chars I often switch to a post flag with a link to the comment my flag is about.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Make the moderator flag comment max length longer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303444/make-the-moderator-flag-comment-max-length-longer) and [Can we get a longer maximum length for messages in custom mod flags on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339044/348196)